Does rotational symmetry imply reflection symmetry for electrostatic interactions?
Consider two charge distributions $\rho_A(\mathbf{x})$ and $\rho_B(\mathbf{x})$. Suppose that the ground state energy of a system of $n$ electrons in a potential generated by the sum of these two charge distributions (along with the electron-electron coulomb interaction) is unchanged under arbitrary rotations of the second charge distribution about some fixed axis, i.e., under the transformation
$$
\rho_A \to \rho_A, \rho_B \to \rho_B'
$$
where
$$
\rho_B'(x,y,z) = \rho_B(x \cos\phi + y \sin\phi,y\cos\phi - x\sin\phi,z)
$$
for any angle $\phi$. We want to include in the ground state energy the mutual interaction between the two charge distributions $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B'$.
Does it necessarily follow that the ground state energy is also unchanged under a reflection of $\rho_B$ about a plane containing the symmetry axis, i.e. under the transformation $\rho_B \to \rho'_B$ where
$$
\rho_B'(x,y,z) = \rho_B(-x,y,z)\,\,?
$$
My intution is telling me that if the interactions are restricted to Coulombic interactions, then there is no way to break the reflection symmetry while keeping the continuous rotational symmetry. An analogy which I feel is relevant is that a two-dimensional function $f(x,y)$ that is invariant under rotations about the origin is also necessarily invariant under arbitrary reflections containing the origin.
